# declaring an array without dimension asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

How can I declare an array without dimension in asp classic?
What I want is, I want to display the `recordset` and save it in an array.

```vb
<tr>
  <td>Call Type</td>
  <%
  dim agentWithCallType( )

  agentWithCallTypeCtr=0
  if not RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType.eof then
    do while not RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType.eof 
  %>
  <td><% =RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType("agentName") %></td>
  <%    
      agentWithCallType(agentWithCallTypeCtr) = RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType("agentName")
      agentWithCallTypeCtr = agentWithCallTypeCtr +1
      RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType.movenext
    loop 
  end if 
  %>
</tr>
```

I get an error on this line.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
>   Subscript out of range

```vb
agentWithCallType(agentWithCallTypeCtr) = RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType("agentName")
```

Comment: Instead using dynamic arrays I suggest looking into `Scripting.Dictionary` object

Comment: @YuriyGalanter If he wants to transpose a `ADODB.Recordset` to an array and don't see what benefit using `Scripting.Dictionary` will give him, plus it's less efficient than using an array as `Scripting.Dictionary` requires COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just assigning the recordset values to an array (and displaying the results in a `TD`). If you want to go from a recordset to an array, you can use the `GetRows()` method of the `Recordset` object. Then you don't have to worry about properly dimensioning your array.

```vb
Dim a
a = RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType.GetRows()

' a is now an array containing your recordset values
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your array, but have failed to declare it's bounds. You want to ReDim your array to tell VBScript how big your array is first:

```vb
Dim agentWithCallType()
ReDim agentWithCallType(0)
```

Alternatively you could just tell it it's 0 size from the get go:

```vb
Dim agentWithCallType(0)
```

Then once you're looping through your recordset, you can increase the size of your array by one for every record you'd like to add:

```vb
ReDim Preserve agentWithCallType(Ubound(agentWithCallType)+1)
```

Comment: @MichaelRosello It might work but this shouldn't be the accepted answer, look at [Bonds answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22337932/692942), there is no need to define your array bounds and even loop through the recordset and populate an array as ADODB provides you with a way to do this `agentWithCallType = RsAgentEffectivenessPerCallType.GetRows()` one line is all you need. Also your method does not create a 2 Dimensional Array which means you lose the context of the row.